# What is the length limit on tag names?

Tags: support, tags

Is there a length limit on tag names? If so, what is it?

Comment: "Your tags couldn't be submitted.  Please see the error above" => "the maximum length is 25 characters".  You might want to read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/).

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/229717/301049/ 233 tags with 25 characters.

Answer (score 15):

As of [2017-08-08](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/162011), tags are capped at 35 chars in length. According to [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> #### How do I create a new tag?
>
> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...
>
> - must be shorter than 35 characters
> - must use the character set `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`

Before 2017-08-08, the limit was 25 characters.