# Case of [gml]: should it only be related to [game-maker-language]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I've seen [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283385/confusion-with-gml-tag), and the result of it is here:

- [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml), which is related to Game Maker Language now, has 222 questions
- [gml-geographic-markup-lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml-geographic-markup-lan), which is about geographic GML, 36 questions, and has *horrible* name. It is not even `[-lang]`, it ends with `-lan`!

But there is also [game-maker-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-language), which is basically means the same as [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) now. This was not mentioned in the previous request.

My suggested plan is:

- Make [game-maker-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-language) a main tag, and [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) a synonym to it. We should do it this way because people still ask questions about geographic GML and tag them with [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) by mistake. This will prevent confusion. The other option will be retag all the questions and kill [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) tag.
- Rename [gml-geographic-markup-lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml-geographic-markup-lan) to some other meaningful name. I think we have a bigger limit on length of a tag name now.

**Edit:**

Turns out GML means at least [6 different languages/technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GML), so maybe we should just burninate the [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) tag/retag all it's questions.

Comment: do know that only recently the tag length went up. It was 25, it is 35 now IIRC.

Comment: If [tag:gml] is used for the markup, I'd say retag and burn that tag to avoid further usage. From what I see people don't care much about the tags once they added them to the question, so it will end up with markup questions tagged as [tag:game-maker-language].

Comment: @Olaf but if they see that is called "`game-maker-language`, also `gml`", this could prevent wrong tagging

Comment: Now I'm really confused. Please come up with your ideas as answers

Comment: @VadimKotov: Problem is the fire&forget practice of many new users. They just don't check the tag has changed, so the markup questions will show up with a ver wrong tag. With [tag:gml] removed competely, this cannot happen. I support your idea renaming the markup tag. `geographic-markup-language` might be the best; the abbreviation can be shown in the short info which pops up anyway. Maybe it's a good idea to split this question into one for each measure and just link each other to show the connection?

Comment: Maybe retag this question as a burninate-request? Then the number of upvotes will determine if we go through with it or not. 20 upvotes needed, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination

Comment: @Lundin ok, makes sense

Comment: @Lundin and now we have 21 upvotes and no downvotes

Comment: Heh I don't even remember this thread :) I think it's been too long and it might be declined for that reason. It's in the hand of the mods now anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Since the GML acronym is so common, and the first instinct of a user of any of the technologies using that acronym would be to create it if they don't find it, burninating the tag is the wrong choice.  We are going to find it recreated again and again until it is blacklisted.  But even then, black listing gml is not going to make finding the tags any easier.

Instead, we need to clearly disambiguate the tags and make them easily found using the tag system.

While a bit redundant and long, I think the best option to improve searchability is to preface each of the tags with `gml-` and then add a descriptive suffix to clearly show the intent of each tag.  Then merge the gml tag into the most common/popular tag (which appears to be [game-maker-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-language)).

- Rename [game-maker-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-language) to [gml-game-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml-game-maker)
- Make [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) a synonym of [gml-game-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml-game-maker)
- Rename [gml-geographic-markup-lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml-geographic-markup-lan) to [gml-geographic-markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml-geographic-markup)
- Rename any tags that exist for any of the other uses of gml using the same format (I see [graph-modelling-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-modelling-language) with 17 questions as well)

I think this is the best option to make it easy for askers to find the specific tag that interests them.

Comment: `gml-geographic-markup-language` consists of 30 characters, which is [within the limit now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272626). Same for `gml-game-maker-language` (23 characters). I'm on the fence about prefixing, it looks a bit weird.

Comment: Whatever tag gml is a synonym for will have to do a lot of cleanup. Better remove the tag completely.

Comment: @Justastudent agree that it looks weird, but I'm trying to make them easier to find for question askers.  If you can't find a tag, then what good is it?

Comment: @BDL I think everyone agrees on that, but that would require blacklisting the tag.

Comment: Don't synonymize [tag:gml] with anything. Just burn it. I'm torn between the simplicity of the other answer's tags and the ease of finding the tags in yours, though.

Comment: @jpmc26 me too, but I think the ease of finding the tags wins out in this  case, assuming people primarily use the acronym gml to refer to these technologies (I wouldn't know, but that's the impression I'm getting). If people commonly refer to them by the full name, that's what I would advocate (e.g. there's a visual-studio tag even though some people refer to it as VS)

Comment: The ideal situation, as I see it, would be for any of the relevant tags to come up if you type in the acronym gml, *and* for them to be named something  similar to  the other answer. Unfortunately, the tag system does not accommodate this.

Comment: @Lauraducky the tag system has a lot of issues.  Ideally, you are correct, which is why I suggested this as a compromise to work within the system we have

Comment: @jpmc26 only reason I am suggesting making it a synonym is to avoid it getting recreated.  I'm convinced that it will happen.  But we can burn it and cross that bridge when we get there

Comment: @psubsee2003 feature request? Unless it's already been requested I guess.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Then you want it blacklisted, not synonymized.

Answer (score 3):

> We should do it this way because people still ask questions about geographic GML and tag them with gml by mistake.

This rather means that the [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) tag should get removed, as it is ambiguous. The sensible way to deal with this would be to:

- Rename [gml-geographic-markup-lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml-geographic-markup-lan) to [geographic-markup-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geographic-markup-language). This should be ok, according to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272625/what-is-the-length-limit-on-tag-names) they increased the tag name length to 35 this summer.
- Go through all posts tagged [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) and retag them either as [game-maker-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-language) or [geographic-markup-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geographic-markup-language). As per usual practice of retagging/burninating, the posts would need to be reviewed at the same time, edited or closed if needed.
- Burninate the [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) tag.

The real question is if this is worth the effort? Is this a big issue?

Comment: Burning the gml tag without a synonym is going to cause it to get recreated.  I know if I were to ask a geographic markup language question, I would look for the [tag:gml] and create it if it didn't.  I assume others who use the gml acronym for other purposes would do the same and we'll end up with the same problem again.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes. That's the fault of SO's tag system, and the policy that burninated tags do not get blacklisted. It is stupid to let anyone and their mother create tags, and it is stupid to not always blacklist burninated tags. But that's a discussion for another post.

Comment: There is one problem with changing [tag:gml-geographic-markup-lan]: users of GML may have trouble finding the tag. That said, it's more likely to be referenced on [GIS.SE] anyway.