# Should the [game-maker] tag be merged/burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

GameMaker tags are a bit of a mess at the moment, you have

- [game-maker-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-language), for the the software's custom scripting language
- [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml), there were a few discussions ([recent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360619/case-of-gml-should-it-only-be-related-to-game-maker-language)) about this being shared by *6* technologies
  (can a tag be blacklisted from creation? Or to display a "which one is yours" dropdown upon attempt to pick it?)
- [game-maker-legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-legacy), containing 4 questions total
  (last version that this tag applies to was released in 2011)
- [gamemaker-studio-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-studio-1.4), previous version of software
  (formally sunset but will still be usable for a while)
- [gamemaker-studio-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-studio-2): current version of software
- [game-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker): tag in question

If you look at each respective tag's questions, game-maker tag is being applied semi-arbitrarily.
If a question is about programming in GM, it would be tagged game-maker-language or gml.
If a question is about using GameMaker (as software), it should be tagged with the appropriate version tag (-legacy, -studio-1.4, -studio-2) - if it is just tagged game-maker, the first comment is going to be asking which version it is for, as UI/functionality differs between major versions (which is why they have their own tags), and 1.4 is still used pretty commonly.

Comment: I believe this is the same mix-up as with [tag:android] and [tag:android-studio]. People confuse language with the IDE.

Comment: I think this a little different because you can't have a GM question without falling into category of it being an IDE question or a programming language question - even the few and between reverse engineering questions apply to a specific version.

Comment: not to forget [game-maker] can also be used as a tag for as a general 'game making' tag, instead of applying for the Studio itself.