# When should a question be tagged [longest-substring] and when should it be tagged [lcs] — or are they synonymous?

Tags: discussion, tags

While poking around to find a duplicate for a question about 'longest common substring', I came across two tags: [lcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lcs) and [longest-substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/longest-substring).  And I came across a number of C questions about longest common substring with neither tag in use.

Both tags have Wikis.  The [lcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lcs) tag has 184 questions; the [longest-substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/longest-substring) tag has 156 questions.

The Wiki for [lcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lcs) says:

> lcs or Longest Common Subsequence is a problem in search optimization: Given two strings, find the common subsequence in given strings with maximum length. The problem can be solved in polynomial time using dynamic programming approach.

The Wiki for [longest-substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/longest-substring) says:

> Longest Substring is a classic computer science problem: given two strings, find the common strings, then return the string(s) in common with the greatest length.

I'm not clear when one should use each tag.  The descriptions are similar.  It seems to be the same problem.  However, the example in the [`lcs` info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lcs/info) seems to allow non-exact substring matching whereas [`longest-substring` info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/longest-substring/info) isn't so clear on whether that is allowed.

- Are the tags synonymous?
- If so, should we make them formally synonymous, and which one should survive (or should a new, currently hypothetical, [longest-common-substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/longest-common-substring) tag be created and the existing tags both be made into synonyms of the new tag)?
- If not, what are the criteria for choosing one or the other?
- Would both tags on a question ever be acceptable?  Why, or why not?

At the moment, this is not a synonym request, but I think it might easily become one.

I think the tags are synonymous and I tend to favour creating the suggested longer but unambiguous tag — assuming that it is not too long to be a valid tag — and making both existing tags into synonyms of the (currently hypothetical) longer tag.

What say you?

Comment: 'longest-common-substring'.length == 24, and [the maximum length of a tag is 35](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272625/215552), so you're good there...

Comment: Since SO is all about implementations: why these tags exist? We don't have a traveling salesman tag despite _every question about algorithms_ being a variation about it. Oh, btw, one of them doesn't exist.

Comment: @Braiam — which "one" doesn't exist?  The (currently hypothetical) [tag:longest-common-substring] tag is known not to exist (unless someone created it today — that wasn't me).  The other two existed when I created this question.

Comment: @Braiam: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traveling-salesman

Comment: @ThomasWeller why the heck there are worse examples?

Comment: "longest substring" doesn't make sense - the longest substring is always the entire string. [longest *common* substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) on the other hand is an on-topic problem

Answer (score 6):

**No**, they are not synonyms.

The [longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) is concerned with substrings, which are *consecutive* subsequences. The problem with two strings of lengths m and n is solvable in O(m + n). The problem with k strings of total length n has an O(nk), hence polynomial, solution.

The [longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) is about finding common subsequences which need not be consecutive. This turns out to be a more computationally intensive task. The problem with two strings of lengths m and n is solvable in O(m * n). The problem with k strings is NP-hard.

Note that Wikipedia pages have a "not to be confused with" link to each other right below the header.

---

So, this answer addresses only the first of your bullet points, but that's a firm "no".

Comment: I would recommend to rename the [longest-substring] tag to [longest-common-substring] and the [lcs] one to [longest-common-subsequence]